# C++ metaprograming to set and get member variables using switch case

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, metaprogramming

Lets say, I have a class, which can have many variables. Each of these variables will have an unique enum mapped to it. I want to set/get values to variables using switch case. Instead of writing each time "case" for each variable, I want to have macro which expands to the set/get functions and corresponding switch case.

```
class myClass
{
  int m_i, m_j;
  void Set(int variable, int i);
  void Get(var variable, int& i);
};

enum var{ VAR_I, VAR_J };

//..........cpp.........
//here I will map enum to member variables
//so if i write this.
//
VARIABLE_START(myClass)
  VARIABLE(VAR_I, m_i)
  VARIABLE(VAR_J, m_j)
VARIABLE_END

//it should expand to....
void myClass::Set(var variable, int i)
{
   switch(var)
   {
      case VAR_I: ....
          break;
      case VAR_J: ....
          break;
  }
}

void myClass::Get(var variable, int& i)
{
   switch(var)
   {
      case VAR_I: ....
          break;
      case VAR_J: ....
          break;
  }
}
```

Now I am facing problem in defining those macros, which should expands to two (or more) member functions with switch cases for each member variable.
Any sort of help is appreciated.

Comment: Would you consider look for some easier alternative approaches to finish the task underlying this question?

Comment: sure,  can you please suggest the alternative approach?

Comment: Say, associative array (aka map or dictionary), array with enum as the index. I don't know what the underlying task is, so all I can offer is some keywords of those alternatives.

Comment: Thanks Nicky,but I was looking in direction of what H Walters has written.It's not just set/get functions, but generating other codes which gets repeated for each variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the preprocessor approach, consider using X-Macros:

```
#define APPLY_MY_VARIABLES \
    MY_VARIABLES(m_i, VAR_I) \
    MY_VARIABLES(m_j, VAR_J)
enum var {
#define MY_VARIABLES(VAR, ENUM) ENUM ,
    APPLY_MY_VARIABLES
#undef  MY_VARIABLES
    // NOTE: The above emits a trailing comma; that's allowed.
    // You may also add another enumerator you can use as a count.
};

class myClass
{
#define MY_VARIABLES(VAR, ENUM) int VAR;
    APPLY_MY_VARIABLES
#undef  MY_VARIABLES
   void Set(var variable, int i);
   void Get(var variable, int& i);
};

void myClass::Set(var variable, int i)
{
   switch(var)
   {
   default: ...
#define MY_VARIABLES(VAR,ENUM) \
      case ENUM: \
          VAR = i; \
          break;
      APPLY_MY_VARIABLES
#undef  MY_VARIABLES
  }
}
void myClass::Get(var variable, int& i)
{
   switch(var)
   {
      default: ...
#define MY_VARIABLES(VAR, ENUM) \
      case ENUM: \
          i = VAR; \
          break;
      APPLY_MY_VARIABLES
#undef  MY_VARIABLES
  }
}
```

The point is that you create a "relation" of tokens--a way to instantiate multiple calls to a macro with the data you want, but you leave those macros undefined. Here, the association is created with a master macro--the apply macro.

At the point of use, you define the macro to expand however you want for some particular purpose, then use the master macro to apply the relation itself.  Immediately after the expansion you should undefine the inner macro (as if you're closing off a for loop).

An alternate approach builds the association by putting the inner macros in a separate file:

**foo.def**

```
MY_VARIABLES(m_i, VAR_I)
MY_VARIABLES(m_j, VAR_J)
```

This file then becomes the relation.  Applying in this case is done by including the file:

```
class myClass
{
#define MY_VARIABLES(VAR, ENUM) int VAR;
#include "foo.def"
#undef  MY_VARIABLES
   void Set(var variable, int i);
   void Get(var variable, int& i);
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.I was not aware of x macros.Now,I will dig more into it

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sketch of the sort of macro-free solution that @NickyC hints
at:

```
// myClass,h
#include <map>

enum var{ VAR_I, VAR_J };

struct myClass
{
    int m_i, m_j;
    void Set(var variable, int i) {
        (this->*map[variable]) = i;
    }
    void Get(var variable, int& i) const {
        i = (this->*map[variable]);
    }
private:
    static std::map<var,int myClass::*> map;
};

// myClass.cpp
std::map<var,int myClass::*> myClass::map = {
    { VAR_I, &myClass::m_i },
    { VAR_J, &myClass::m_j }
};
```

It rests on mapping `var` values to members of `myClass`. To test,
append:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    myClass mc;
    mc.Set(VAR_I,2);
    mc.Set(VAR_J,4);
    int i, j;
    mc.Get(VAR_I,i);
    mc.Get(VAR_J,j);
    cout << i << '\n' << j << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2
4
```

Note incidentally that:

```
    void Get(var variable, int& i) const {
        i = (this->*map[variable]);
        // or whatever
    }
```

is very likely less convenient than:

```
    int const & Get(var variable) const {
        return (this->*map[variable]);
        // or whatever
    }
```

(gcc 4.9.2, -std=c++11)

Comment: Hello Mike, I think this will not be straight forward to me, as my data members can be of any type, like int, float, etc,..But I will see if I can use union and do something. Thanks a lot